# Does using a pipeline with CountVectorizer and TfidfTransform convert the input data into a document-term matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

Does the following code actually converts the input into a dtm since it's not using the fit_transform method but only fit in order to learn the vocabulary? Is this model sufficient for learning ?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.data, df.target, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42) 

pipeline = Pipeline(
    [
        ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('logreg', LogisticRegression()),
    ]
)
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred= pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: What do you mean by **dtm** in "Does the following code actually converts the input into a **dtm**.."?

Comment: document term matrix. is it nandatory to convert into dtm for ml algorithms in classification?

Comment: I've added more details to my answer specifically for this part.

Comment: so if I have multiple rows for one column 'text' for example, if each row contains a single sentence represented as a bag of words after text processing, would you consider that as a document with multiple sentences or each sentence is a document? is converting the inputs as dtm useful in this situation?

Comment: I wasn't accurate when I said that earlier and I'm sorry if I made you confused. A document could be just one sentence or multiple sentences as long as they have the same label

Answer (score 0):

First, let's start with the simple question in the headline; does we have to use document-term matrix with machine learning algorithms for classification?

The answer is kinda... All we need to do is a feature-space. A space where there are numbers instead of words a space where we can perform mathematics upon. This space could be (document x word) as in your case or (word x word) or even (word x dependency relation). It all depends on how do you wanna extract the features.

Is this pipeline a valid way to classify? The answer is yes, this is a simple pipeline to extract features and use these features to classify. Here is a full example where you can see that it does a pretty good job in classification:

```
#import needed modules
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# obtain the data (download if needed)
df = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=['alt.atheism', 'talk.religion.misc'])

# Use your classifier
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('logreg', LogisticRegression()),
])

# split the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.data, df.target, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42) 

# train
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict
y_pred= pipeline.predict(X_test)

#evaluate
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
#0.9127906976744186
```

As you can see, it does a pretty good job as a start. Let's get to the third question, in the above model we used `fit` not `fit_transform` is this OK? Yes, the only difference between `fit_transform` is a function that does two things `fit` and `transform`, we only need `fit` here. We can use `fit_transform` if we want to predict the classes of the training data.

Hopefully, this answers your question!!